# How to keep text alignment right in extra max font size iOS

Tags: ios

I have a table cell with Basic style, right text alignment set up using storyboard.
When user sets the font size of the phone to extra max, the text jumps to the left (The text's size is fixed so it doesn't go big though).

How to keep the text remain on the right?

- With normal font size

[image]

- With extra max font size
  [image]

How to set font size to extra max:
Settings > Accessibility > Display & Text Size > Larger Text > On & set to max size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a `Basic` style table view cell, the text *alignment* doesn't change ... the label constraints change.

Use a `Custom` cell style, add a label, set the label font to `Body`.